# Why Past Perfect In Specified Sentence

Tags: word-usage, past-perfect

I am reading *The Valley of Fear* by Arthur Conan Doyle.
And in the fourth chapter we have this part:

> "It all could have been arranged. Mr Douglas was an American, or had lived in America for a long time.
>   So had Mr Barker."
>   "Ames, the butler--"
>   "What about him? Is he reliable?"
>   "ten years with Sir Charles Chandos--as solid as a rock. He has been with Douglas ever since he took the Manor House five years ago. He has never seen a gun of this sort in the house"
>   "The gun could fit into any box. How could he swear there was no such gun in the house?"
>   "Well, anyhow, **he had never seen** one."

And according to *Advanced Learners' Grammar* by Mark Foley & Diane Hall - **Past Perfect** is usually used in: actions and states before a time in the past, a sequence in the past, or to describe unfulfilled intentions.

But in this sentence "he had never seen one" I do not really feel the usage of this tense. 
Is it implied that:- he had never seen one (before we spoke with him)"?
Or are there any other explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"How could he swear there was no such gun in the house?"**.

This is a rhetorical question which was posed "at some time in the past".

**"He had never seen one"** refers to a time before that time in the past.

Hence it is written in the past perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Compare:

> Q1: *How **can** he swear there was no gun in the house? A1: He **has
>   never seen** one [as of now].*
>
> Q2: *How **could** he swear there was no gun in the house? A2: He
>   **had never seen** one [as of the time he swore].*

Even if it's still true that he has yet to see a gun, the tense in A2 is backshifted to suit the past sense in Q2.

Comment: And this differs significantly from the previous answer in that it ...? (Remember, ELU is for linguists rather than novices.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: It branches at an earlier point for benefit of the OP's understanding: It shows that by examining the modal auxiliary — understanding the relationship between the present sense of *can* and the past sense of *could* — we can place the question as being "posed at some time in the past." If that answer is too remedial for this site, then so is the question.